# How to make an immutable map given a map using Guava?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, guava

Given a Map, how can I make an immutable map using Guava? I know one way through `Collections.unmodifiableMap` but is there any other way using Guava?

```
Map<String, String> realMap = Maps.newHashMap();
realMap.put("A", "B");

// any other alternative?
Map<String, String> unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(realMap);
```

I am populating my `realMap` with some entries and then I need to make it Immutable so that no one can modify it. I am just trying to see if there is any alternative using Guava? I did some search but I cannot find it.

Comment: Really? That's about 1 sec of research on the internet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`ImmutableMap.copyOf()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#copyOf(java.util.Map)):

```
ImmutableMap<String, String> immutableMap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(realMap);
```

Keep in mind that, as opposed to `unmodifiableMap()` which only creates a *wrapper* to its argument, this actually copies it to a new map. That can mean a slight performance hit, but it also means there's no possibility of the map being modified accidentally through `realMap`.